# Multiple MongoDB queries in a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function

How can I execute the following queries together in a single javascript function for mongoDB?

```
//find the reviews from the reviews collection
var proRev = db.reviews.find({productID: "123"}).toArray();
//update the products collection
db.products.update({productID : "123"},{$push:{Reviews:proRev}},{multi:true});
//remove the reviews from the reviews collection
db.reviews.remove({productID: "123"});
```

The function would be based on finding the reviews for productID "123" from a reviews collection, and inserting them as an array, in a new field for productID "123" found in the products collection.

Rather than executing the queries seperate, I would like them to execute in a single function - I'm a javascript noob so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Example:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'myproject';

(async function() {
  let client;

  try {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    const db = client.db(dbName);

    const [res1, res2] = await Promise.all([
      db.collection('inserts').findOne({
        foo: "bar"
      }),
      db.collection('inserts').findOne({
        bar: "foo"
      })
    ]);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  }

  // Close connection
  client.close();
})();
```

If you want to do it in one operation within MongoDB, try using [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)